# Adobe Air with a capture card

Tags: video, air, adobe, camera, capture

is it possible to get the video stream of a capturecard into adobe air?
I think on linux there is it possible to setting up a capture card as a "normal" camera in /dev/video0

I have a Blackmagic intensity pro (with HDMI) capturecard and now I want to show this video stream in an adobe air app.

someone any ideas?

EDIT:
Or is it easier to create a local video stream with another software? Adobe air can get the live stream via localhost or something else. requirement: stream from capturecard/camera have to be live (without delay).

Damian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your best bet is probably to use adobe's flash media encoder to stream it to the localhost